# Extended syntax for passing parameters to KnockoutJS templates

Tags: knockout.js

I have come across several situations in which I have to code my template call like this:

```
<!-- ko template: {name: 'paginatedList', 
                   data: {listContainer: paginatedResults, itemTemplate: $parent.template}} --> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

because in addition to my data object (e.g., `paginatedResults`), I need to pass in supplemental information such as the name of the template to use in rendering items. As another example, when rendering an item in a list, I might need to know the current settings of a filter that is stored in some context logically far-removed from the item in a list.

Rather than having to contort my data model (in the above example, replacing `paginatedResults` with `{listContainer: paginatedResults, itemTemplate: $parent.template}}`, it would be nice to have a bit of syntax on templates that allows me to pass around (and acccrue as templates are evaluated hierarchically) some extra context that a deeply-nested template might need when rendering itself.

I guess what I wondering about is the feasibility of adding an extra (optional) parameter to the `ko.bindingHandlers` functions (`init` and `update`) to make them look like this:

```
function (element, 
          valueAccessor, 
          allBindingsAccessor, 
          viewModel, 
          bindingContext, 
          context)
```

When coding the above example, I ought to be able to say something like

```
<!-- ko template: {name: 'paginatedList', 
                   data: paginatedResults, 
                   context: {itemTemplate: $parent.template}} --> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

or better yet,

```
<!-- ko template: {name: 'paginatedList', 
                   data: paginatedResults, 
                   itemTemplate: $parent.template} --> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

and have `itemTemplate` become a variable I can refer to in nested templates and `data-bind` attributes.

Does this make sense? I don't have a good understanding of how hard this would be to implement. I guess one thing to worry about are name collisions, but some naming conventions might circumvent that.

Gene

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without changes to Knockout core, I think that the best that you could do is a wrapper binding that creates a structure similar to what you currently are passing.

Binding might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templateWithContext = {
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        ko.utils.extend(context, options.context);

        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply(this, arguments);
    } 
};
```

You would call it like:

```
<div data-bind="templateWithContext: { name: 'itemsTmpl', data: items, context: { title: 'First' } }"></div>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QNvFn/

It looks like you are using native templates, but if you are using jQuery Templates still, then it did include a `templateOptions` [feature](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-reusing-template-by-passing.html) that used the `options` feature of jQuery Templates to pass context data.  This is not available in the native templates.  The general recommendation now is to use the `$root`, `$parent`, and `$parents` [variables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_2_referring_to_parent_binding_contexts_using_parent_parents_and_root) to access the information or to pass an object as `data` in the way that you described in your post.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it sort of does the right thing, but isn't enough to warrant an extra binding handler. Would be interesting to see how often this pattern comes up in complex applications.

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot. If I write a template wrapper, can I set the template name inside the `init` ?

Comment: @tbruyelle - you definitely can set the name.  The idea would be that inside your wrapper binding you build up the options that you want to pass to the real template binding.  Here is a sample that is maybe a bit more generic than you need (you could just set name on the valueAccessor() object):  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7rcFD/

Comment: That might not be the right link that you posted.  Looks like the same as mine.

Comment: Thanks for your sample, I also find a solution http://jsfiddle.net/VhbXm/5/ There is less code than your solution but I don't know if it's better.

Comment: My sample was trying to show a generic structure that you could build off of.  If you want a more hard-coded approach, then you can simplify yours down to: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/VhbXm/6/.  There is a subtle reason why the `init` function should really pass a `name`, but it really will have no effect on your functionality.  Basically, if a 'name' is not available in 'init', then it will assume that you are using anonymous templates and try to copy the children of your element as the template.  However, this is not used in the `update` function, as you added a name there.

Comment: This no longer seems to be functioning with Knockout 3.0.0